# Send Xml data to webapi apicontroller parameter value null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I want to send xmldata via fiddler to my wepabi, but my webapi doesn't get the data for some reason. I want to know the reason;)

What I have:

```
[RoutePrefix("Document")]
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddDocument")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddDocument([FromBody] XmlDocument doc)
    {
        //  Do Stuff
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

What my fiddler looks like
[image: FiddlerRequest]

When I do this request `doc` is always `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use content negotiation you need to accept a class which the model binder can bind to in your controller. Like this:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Active { get; set; }
    public Page[] Pages { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string InternalId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Then you accept this as your argument instead of a `XmlDocument`:

```
[RoutePrefix("Document")]
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("AddDocument")]
    public IHttpActionResult AddDocument([FromBody] Document doc)
    {
        //  Do Stuff
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

And now you can change the `Content-Type` header in your request to be either `application/xml`, `text/xml` or `application/json` depending on the format being posted.

Comment: Your solutions works when I change the xmlns in my request. I dont really want to change that, but then I get the following error: `Expecting element 'Document' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/NoteStop.Models'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Document', 
namespace 'http://www.lias.nl/schemas/notestop-document'`

Is there a way to change the notestop.models namespace?

Comment: You can annotate your `Document` class with the `XmlRoot` attribute and specify your namespace. `[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.lias.nl/schemas/notestop-document")]`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but sadly it did not work. Got the same error. For now I give the `HttpRequestMessage request` as a parameter and extreact the xml from the content. But not ideal...